# Confusion regarding indefinite integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals

Consider the integral

$$
\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{x(3+\sin(\log(x))}.
$$
Since $$\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{x(3+\sin(\log(x))}>\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{4x}$$.

The considered integral is infinite.

However, if we compute the anti-derivative of the function, we get,

$$
\int_t^1 \frac{dx}{x(3+\sin(\log(x))}=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\tan^{-1}(\frac{1}{2\sqrt2})-\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{3\tan\left(\frac{\log(t)}{2}\right)+1}{2\sqrt2}\right).
$$

Clearly, if we take $t\rightarrow 0$, RHS will not diverge to infinity due to the $\tan^{-1}$ term.
What am I missing here? I think it has to be something to do with the branch of $\tan^{-1}$.

Comment: the anti derivative is problematic because of the $\tan^{-1}$ (with the correct branch) and $\tan$ and $\log$ and how they interact. For example, as you decrease $t$ to $0$, $\log t$ goes to $-\infty$. So, the composition $\tan(\log(t)/2)$ doesn’t really make sense for all values of $t\in (0,\infty)$. You’re going to have to skip those values of $t$ such that $(\log t)/2$ is an odd integer multiple of $\pi/2$. Then you have to apply the correct branch of $\tan^{-1}$ so that you get a continuous function of $t$ on the RHS (since the LHS is clearly continuous). It’s just all a big mess.

Comment: Thanks!! Got it!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the term $\tan\left(\frac{\log(t)}{2}\right)$. Note that the domain of $\tan (x)$ is $x\neq n\pi+\frac\pi2$ for $n\in \mathrm Z$. So when $t\to 0^+$, $\log(t)$ passes through $n\pi+\frac\pi2$ for $n\in \mathrm Z^-$ and hence $\tan\left(\frac{\log(t)}{2}\right)$ changes from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ or from $\infty$ to $-\infty$ infinitely times. Thus
$$ \lim_{t\to0^+}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{3\tan\left(\frac{\log(t)}{2}\right)+1}{2\sqrt2}\right) $$
does not make sense.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have the same suspicion.

Comment: You are missing the point here, I think. Even if the limit existed, you would still get a wrong result. For example, if you put the right value of $t$, you can even get negative values, which is clearly absurd. The function $t \mapsto \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{3\tan\left(\frac{\log(t)}{2}\right)+1}{2\sqrt2}\right)$ just isn't an antiderivative on the whole domain as it is not differentiable and so the fundamental theorem of calculus is not applicable.

Comment: It’s not just an issue of the limit not existing. It is a combination of the issue you mentioned regarding $\tan(\log (t)/2)$, and the fact that one has to change the branch of $\tan^{-1}$ used infinitely many times. If we could maintain a fixed branch then one could simply say that the $\liminf$ of the integral is infinite, while the $\liminf$ of the expression on the right is finite.